# qtip - how to - content: { "prepend some text to an" attr : 'id'},

Tags: jquery, attr, qtip

I have this working for my qtip

```
        /* required for qtip crests to crests */
        var countyCrest =   {
                content: {
                    attr: 'id'
                },
                position: {
                    target: 'mouse',
                    adjust: {
                        mouse: true,
                        y: +10
                    }
                },
                style: {
                    classes: 'ui-tooltip-tipsy ui-tooltip-shadow',
                    tip: true
                }
        };/* end for qtip crests to crests */
```

and I would like to prepend "Co. " before each attr: 'id'. I tried various versions of

```
content: {
            "Co. "+attr: 'id'
},
```

which does not work. 
Could anyone point me in the right direction?
tia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better would be like following:

```
var temp = {};

temp['Co. ' + attr] = 'id'; 
 var countyCrest =   {

     content: temp,
    ...
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qxk6k/)**

---

#### Note

String concatenation of `Object` property as you tried is not possible.

---

#### If you want answer like @Christoph then you don't need concatenation, write simply like

```
content: {
            attr: 'Co.id'
}
```

Comment: 1. This is the same as the OPs solution only that you have put it into a var. This it should not work either. 2. Your demo is useless.

Comment: @Christoph do you check my demo and `console.log`, I think no. There is a lot of difference between my code and OP's code. You should look my demo and console.log carefully and make a lot of study on object. Don't Down vote any one if you don't have enough knowledge about that

Comment: @chris check my demo and `console.log` carefully, I think you'll get your answer

Comment: You are right about the concatenation but most likely this won't fix the problem.

Comment: And regarding to your demo: console.logging proves, that your object is correct, but doesn't prove that this actually alters the element in the correct way.

Comment: @thecodeparadox Unfortunately I could not get this to work. This is the code that adds qtip.

`$("#selectResult").append("<div id='"+arr[this.id]+
"' class='inline'></div>");

var addThis = arr[this.id];
 
$("#"+addThis).css({'background-image' : 'url(./img/coatofarms/'  +arr[this.id]+'.png)','background-repeat': 'no-repeat','background-position': 'bottom'}).qtip(countyCrest);
}`

this adds a new div and then sets the background image and it works fine. The problems is the qtip displays the id name e.g. 'Galway' and I would like it to display 'Co. Galway'

Comment: apologies for the formatting, I'm still learning the stackoverflow interface

Comment: I avoided the issue by adding a title to my appends and attr: 'title'

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact, that I can't see the `attr` option for the content property ([Documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#content)) (might be another version or whatever), i guess it should be:

```
content: {
            attr: 'Co.'+'id'
},
```

(spaces are not allowed in `id` attributes) instead of

```
content: {
            "Co. "+attr: 'id'
},
```

since you don't want to alter the name of the option (which is fixed `attr`) but the value of it.

Comment: I think OP doesn't asked about for that

Comment: @thecodeparadox might be. However, I understood it this way. If not I will simply delete my answer, no problem.